# How do you measure the bandwidth used by a given process after it has completed, on Linux?

Tags: linux, process, bandwidth

Is there a way to get a summary of how much bandwidth a given process used on Linux after the process completes?  I do not want a monitor, I want something I can look at after the task has completed..

Ideally something like the "time" command or a profiler, but for network usage.

Answer (score 1):

You could use http://nethogs.sourceforge.net/

You might also want to look through the answers given at https://serverfault.com/questions/44492/ip-process-based-bandwidth-usage-stats-tool-for-linux

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to count packets in and out using iptables based on a PID, I understand that knowing the PID before a process is starting is next to impossible. Depending on your situation this maybe reliant.

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p TCP -m owner --pid-owner $PID -j ACCEPT
```

You can check if the rule is being hit and how many packets have hit it, with the following command.

```
iptables-save -c
```

Answer (score 0):

[tcptrace](http://www.tcptrace.org/) is quite powerful and is probably able to do the things you want. Maybe it's a bit too low-level though...

Answer (score 0):

Invoke the process from a script that awaits user input after completing the main process. This way, it doesn't terminate and you can use ntop or nethogs to see how much it downloaded/uploaded.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).